# Can we define 4/8 = 8 mod 10?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This question came to mind when I saw another question involving modular-arithmetic division.

In $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ we can divide 4 by 7 by identifying 3 as a multiplicative inverse of 7 and multiplying 4 by that inverse, thus $4\cdot3=2$.  This does not work for $4/8$ because 8 does not have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

But suppose I identify a multiplicative subgroup ${2,4,6,8}$ with 6 as the identity element.  Now 8 does have an inverse, namely 2, and so $4/8=4\cdot2=8$.

Is this legitimate?  If so, so we see the concept applied in mathematical problems?

Comment: This is as legit as homeopathic medicine

Comment: You can't simply declare that $6$ is the identity element - it doesn't have the properties that a multiplicative identity element must have, namely that $x \cdot 6=x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It does so within the group ${2,4,6,8}$.  It seems unconventional but it seems to work.  And I understand that the oroposal woukd apply only within this group not all modulo 10 residues.

Comment: 6 = 1 mod 5....

Comment: Well, the subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and 6 corresponds to the identity element. I'm not sure what your actual question is, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define "division." One defensible definition of "divide $\bar 4$ by $\bar 8$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ is to ask for $\bar a$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ so that $\bar 8 \cdot \bar a = \bar 4$. Problem is, with this definition, you may have no results or TOO MANY results. It is not reasonable to define $\bar 4 / \bar 8 = \bar 8$, because that leaves out the other equally valid and fundamentally different "answer," namely $\bar 3$. So we can have a legitimate definition of "divide by" but probably not for a symbol like $\bar 4 / \bar 8$ (unless you are willing to assign to that symbol the set of ALL answers).

The subgroup argument doesn't seem reasonable; what if you could find more than one multiplicative group that includes both "4" and "8" - and 4/8 depends on which such group you are looking at?

Comment: in the case discussed here the subgroup is unique, but the point is taken.  We'd have to specify the subgroup.  Presumably this inhibits the use of this subgroup division concept?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot uniquely define $4/8$ to be $8$ mod $10$, but it makes sense. The natural way to interpret what $4/8$ should be is: any number which, when multiplied by $8$, gives $4$. Of course, $8\cdot 8 = 64 \equiv 4$ (mod $10$). Since division w.r.t. a composite modulus is not single-valued, it is perhaps wrong to write "$4/8 \equiv 8$", for it could lead to contradictions: we also have $8 \cdot 3 = 24 \equiv 4$ (mod $10$), so $3$ and $8$ are distinct solutions to $8x \equiv 4$ (mod $10$) and thus $3 \equiv 4/8 \equiv 8$ !! It would make more sense to define $4/8$ (mod $10$) as the *set* of residues $\{3, 8\}$.